# Submit intent schema for slots and utterances for an Alexa Skill in JSON form?

Tags: amazon-web-services, schema, speech-recognition, alexa-skills-kit

Currently the only way I know how to submit the *slots* and *utterances* definitions for an Alexa Skill is through the GUI form based model builder you find at this base URL:

```
https://developer.amazon.com/alexa/console/ask/build/
```

I need to submit a huge number of sample utterances for each of my intents that are generated automatically from code I've written.  This makes using the GUI at the link above a wildly painful experience.

Is there some way to submit the definition/schema for an *intent* in raw text or JSON format for my Alexa Skill via the Alexa or AWS consoles?  If so, how?

I'm still stunned I can't get the raw speech recognition input directly.  I've tried the *Amazon.Literal* and *Amazon.SearchQuery* slots but that still doesn't get you the same level of quality and versatility as the raw speech recognition results you get from Google's speech recognition engine when developing a Google Home or Google Assistant app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for your insertion problem try the JSON editor in the build section of the developer console. It's the last point of "Interaction model" on the left hand side. This way you can bulk-insert sample utterances in JSON format.

Alternatively you could clone the model using the ASK CLI:
https://developer.amazon.com/de/docs/smapi/ask-cli-command-reference.html#clone-command
After cloning, you can edit it locally and then redeploy it.

Hope that helps :)